# Error with Spring MVC No implementation for java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLParserFactory>

Tags: spring-mvc, semantic-web, protege

I'm developing a Spring MVC application who will access to knowledge base.
My knowledge base si base on RDF and i'm using SQWRL (https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRL).

When i deploy on a standalone application, I don't have errors.

When I deploy in a Spring app with Spring MVC and Pivotal, I have the following error:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

type Rapport d''exception

message Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête. 

exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLParserFactory> was bound.
while locating java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLParserFactory>
for parameter 0 at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyParsers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1395)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyParsers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1395)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLAPIImplModule.configure(OWLAPIImplModule.java:61)

2) No implementation for java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerFactory> was bound.
while locating java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerFactory>
for parameter 0 at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyStorers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyStorers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLAPIImplModule.configure(OWLAPIImplModule.java:61)

3) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Injection failed for factory: interface org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDocumentFormatFactory type: interface org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDocumentFormat
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)

3 errors
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My controller is:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.swrlapi.factory.SWRLAPIFactory;
import org.swrlapi.parser.SWRLParseException;
import org.swrlapi.sqwrl.SQWRLQueryEngine;
import org.swrlapi.sqwrl.SQWRLResult;
import org.swrlapi.sqwrl.exceptions.SQWRLException;

OWLOntologyManager ontologyManager;
OWLOntology ontology;
SQWRLQueryEngine queryEngine;
/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */

/**
 * Index page
 */

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(){
//      String generalInfo = this.generalInformations();
    String test = this.test();
    return "index";
}
public void init() {
    ontologyManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    try {
        ontologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument
        (new File((System.getProperty("user.dir"))+"/resources/epicam_v2.owl"));
    SWRLAPIFactory.createSQWRLQueryEngine(ontology);
    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

**The libraries add to the project are :**

```
drools-compiler-6.4.0.Final.jar
drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar
drools-decisiontables-6.4.0.Final.jar
drools-osgi-integration-6.4.0.Final.jar
drools-reteoo-6.4.0.Final.jar
drools-templates-6.4.0.Final.jar
guava-18.0.jar
guice-4.0.jar
guice-assistedinject-4.0.jar
guice-multibindings-4.0.jar
jgoodies-common-1.6.0.jar
jgoodies-looks-2.5.3.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
knowledge-api-6.4.0.Final.jar
owlapi-osgidistribution-4.2.5.jar
poi-3.13.jar
semargl-core-0.6.1.jar
semargl-rdf-0.6.1.jar
semargl-rdfa-0.6.1.jar
swrlapi-1.0.12.jar
swrlapi-drools-engine-1.0.12.jar
swrltab-plugin-1.0.12.jar
```

**Full stack of the error : **

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
sept. 18, 2016 2:06:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 3468 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Sep 18 02:06:56 WAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e71a069: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4243 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Sep 18 02:06:59 WAT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
WARN : org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.Profile+Annotation
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@fcb50ef: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e71a069
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: fr.ummisco.oepicam.HomeController; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdk/Profile+Annotation.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:267)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdk/Profile+Annotation.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:45)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.findAllAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    ... 26 more
sept. 18, 2016 2:07:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 16980 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Sep 18 02:07:03 WAT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
WARN : org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.Profile+Annotation
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@65996c32: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e71a069
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: fr.ummisco.oepicam.HomeController; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdk/Profile+Annotation.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:267)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdk/Profile+Annotation.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:45)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.findAllAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Looks like not all owlapi jars are on the classpath. Can you get a list of the actual jars you have and add it to the question?

Comment: @Ignazio : Ok, i have. add it

Answer (score 0):

The owlapi-osgidistribution does not embed all third party dependencies, and it looks like they are missing in your setup. The full list is available here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.owlapi%7Cowlapi-osgidistribution%7C4.2.5%7Cbundle

Comment: Thank you. The error is resolved. But i have another one : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.Profile+Annotation

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: Which class is not found? jdk.Profile+Annotation. Another information on error is : java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdk/Profile+Annotation.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist. I have add the full stack of error above

Comment: That's an unusual class name as + cannot be part of a class name and is not used in anonymous inner classes either. However, the stack trace mentions only Spring and Tomcat classes, so it seems to be a Spring MVC issue rather than an OWLAPI related issue. I could not find anything useful on that topic.